# Gitlab E2E test issues

Tags: npm, gitlab, devops

Currently we run end to end test in a Gitlab resource. The issue is that to run the end-to-end test we need a PouchDB database, and Gitlab does not persist the data. Therefore every time we run the test we have to push the database to Gitlab repo. The problem with this is that changes to the database are reflected in our merge requests and that is creating confusion and additional work for manual merge.

I would like to know how can this be resolved and what all solutions are the best in this scenario

As mentioned we are pushing DB results to repo